# Excel Task pane not loading due to Addin error

Tags: office-js

When running Excel application in office JS getting below error in task pane for some time not always.

ADD-IN ERROR
This add-in could not be started.Close this dialog to ignore the problem or click "Restart" try again.

Tried below enabling in settings in ie.

Internet options --> Security --> Internet --> Enabled protected mode
Internet options --> Security --> Restricted Sites--> Enabled protected mode

Expected result: When running Excel application Task pane should load with UI.(was working fine)
Actual result :Even configured suggested settings in IE still add-in error showing in some time on task pane.

Comment: Add your code here to check for possible error. The task pane will not load if it has error.

Comment: Previously it was showing always then we fixed this based on IE setting as mentioned in earlier comments. But now it is appearing of and on even required IE settings configured. Hence not sure what code to add here. Kindly advise.

Comment: Do you load the add-in from a button on the ribbon or was it opening automatically?

Comment: It is getting loaded add-in from a button in the ribbon. Kindly confirm the checks need to do in browser settings or anything in manifest file,

Comment: @Rick, Any update please..

Comment: Hi, We fixed this issue. It is due to some code changes of reading config file hence by changing the same it is fixed now.